# Clickhouse external dictionary returns inconsistent results

Tags: clickhouse, eventual-consistency

We have a dictionary whose source is an external postgres, the layout is `complex_key_cache` and the `lifetime` is 3600-7200.

When I do

```
select * from dictionaries.dictname limit 5
```

I only get some results (less than 5, I think the dict has about 10k rows). But if I do

```
SELECT dictGet('dictname', 'catId', tuple('somestring'))
```

then assuming the key exists I always get a result. And on some of the next calls to `select *` I will get that row (key `somestring`) returned.

And the same happens with this query

```
SELECT d,
       catId,
       dictGet('dictname', 'catId', tuple(base64Decode(d))) AS categoryId
  FROM dictionaries.dictname
```

I only get some results - probably the ones that are in cache.

So 2 questions:

How can I ensure that I get all results given a list? eg.

```
SELECT d,
       catId
  FROM dictionaries.dictname d
 WHERE d in ('somestring', 'anotherstring')
```

And why does this happen? Why does a *single* `dictGet` seem to work (doesn't use cache?) but when I try to use `IN` operator or the `dictGet` joined with the dict table it doesnt work (seems to use some kind of cache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, since this dict uses `complex_key_cache` clickhouse only uses the cache when not filtering (eg listing all keys in dict) and uses the cache and maybe the source when *filtering* for results.

This query was using the cached dict in the `FROM` clause and so the filtering was applied to the cached dict:

```
SELECT d,
       catId
  FROM dictionaries.dictname d
 WHERE d in ('somestring', 'anotherstring')
```

but if we do it this way

```
SELECT d,
       dictGet('dictname', 'category_id', tuple(d)) AS categoryId
  FROM (
        SELECT ['somestring', 'anotherstring'] AS d
       ) ARRAY
  JOIN d
```

it forces the `dictGet` to go the source if it doesn't find the key in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For cached dictionaries the dictionary table reflects only rows cached by dictGet.